# How do you turn on root lines Windows Explorer, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

In Windows 7 Windows Explorer, the folders along the left line of the screen do not have the "root lines" found in XP, the lines to the left of the folder names that make it easy to see which folders are at the same level. Is it possible to enable this in Windows 7?

Comment: look at my comment in John T answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been removed in Windows 7 among some other features as listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_features_removed_in_Windows_7). See the 4th point under **[Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_features_removed_in_Windows_7#Windows_Explorer)**. If you are interested in 3rd party tools, check out [xplorer²](http://www.zabkat.com/) which has this functionality:

[image]

Comment: I don't have that option. I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium -- is that the problem? Is there another setting that could enable this option?

Comment: What option? The folder options is missing? or the checkbox?

Comment: "Display simple folder view in Navigation pane" is not under Folder Options, View Tab. I think it was in Vista but removed in Windows 7.

Comment: You're correct.

Comment: Its not in the view tab but general tab in my version (Ultimate)

Comment: If the option is in Ultimate, is there a registry entry that can enable it in other versions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Windows 7, but in Windows XP that "feature" is enabled by disabling "Simple Folder View".  Thank you, MS.

For XP, Windows Explorer:

- Tools | Options menu
- View tab
- Uncheck "Display simple folder view in Explorer's Folders list"

I hope that it's something similar in Windows 7.  I feel the same as you, removing the tree lines doesn't actually make the view "simpler".

Answer (score 0):

did you try to click on the bar once(open area).  after doing so it will give you the full address in windows 7

Comment: Yes, I can see the full address. I would like to see the lines along the left side of the folders that shows their level. Microsoft apparently removed this feature from Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Classic Shell's Classic Explorer](http://www.classicshell.net/features/#explorer). Set ***Navigation pane style*** to *Windows XP Classic:*

[image: Classic Explorer Settings - Navigation pane style]